# Не работает валидация по MIME

Tags: php, laravel

вьюха:

```
    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'form_store','files' => true]) !!}
    ...
    {!! Form::file('files[]', ['multiple'=>true, 'data-multiple-caption'=>"{count} files selected"]) !!}
    ...
```

контроллер:

```
public function store(FormRequest $request)
    {
        foreach ($request->file() as $file) {
            foreach ($file as $f) {
                $name = md5($f).'.'.$f->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $f->move(public_path('files/form/'.$id.'/'), $name);
            }
        }
    }
```

Request:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'contact' => 'required',
        'text' => 'required',
        'files.*' => 'mimetypes:text/*'
    ];

    return $rules;
}
```

Проблема в том, что при данных `$rules` не пропускает `.txt`, а вот так `'files.*' => 'mimetypes:text/plain'` - пропускает.

Answer (score 1):

В правилах нельзя задать с вайлдкардом как вы хотите:

```
mimetypes:text/*
```

Тип должен быть из [этого списка](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types).

Как альтернативу попробуйте валидатор `mimes`:

```
'mimes:txt'
```

Comment: Я рассматривал этот вариант, но мне нужно "разрешить" около 200 различных расширений) Поэтому и пытался "сгруппировать"

Comment: Можно попробовать написать свой валидатор и в нём сделать такую проверку, но кастомных валидаторов для файлов я не писал, не знаю что туда передается.